# How to update different table data from uploaded csv file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

**EDIT**

I already make csv file upload. But now, I want to update data from uploaded csv file. If the csv data is already exists in table, I need to update that data and if not, I insert as a new record. This is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['import'])) { //import csv file into database
    if(isset($_FILES['csv']['name'])) {
        $file_type = explode('.',$_FILES['csv']['name']);
        if($file_type[1]=="csv") {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $data = array();
            while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != FALSE ){
                    $id=$data[0];
                    $a = $data[1];
                    $b = $data[2];
                    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',time());

                $sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table LIKE question;

                        LOAD DATA INFILE '$file_name'
                        INTO TABLE temp_table
                        fields terminated by ','
                        optionally enclosed by ''
                        lines terminated by '\r\n'
                        (id, question, ans_number, a_one, a_two, a_three, a_four, a_five); 

                        UPDATE question
                        INNER JOIN temp_table on temp_table.id = question.id
                        SET question.question = temp_table.question;

                        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;";
                mysql_db_query($dbname, $sql)or die(mysql_error());
                $insert_id =  mysql_insert_id(); 
                echo "insert id: $insert_id<br/><br/>";
                exit();

                $count = 0;
                for($j=2;$j<count($data);$j++) {
                    $b_name = $data[$j];
                    $count++;
                    if($count == $b) {
                        $is_answer = yes;
                    }else {
                        $is_answer = no;
                    }
                    if($b_name != "") {
                        ***#I want to update and insert here***
                        $ans_sql = "INSERT INTO a_table(name,is_answer,id) VALUES('$b','$is_answer','$insert_id')";
                        mysql_db_query($dbname, $ans_sql);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the error every time like this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'Question.csv' INTO TABLE temp_table fields ter' at line 3
```

In my csv file, I have data like this

```
id, question, ans_number, a_one, a_two, a_three, a_four, a_five
```

but I want to add only question into my question table with the related id.
And other data are add to the another table.

I'm not sure whats wrong in my syntax. How to solve it please?

Comment: Hello, try taking a look at [insert ... update query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), in order to use this, you will need atleast 1 unique column to identify when a column already exists...

Comment: Hi Naruto, I try with your advice. But its not ok. If you have the other way something like LOAD DATA INFILE, please share me with sample. Because I'm a new in php development.

Comment: You can only pass a single SQL statement per `mysql_db_query` call. You could start there.

Comment: After I change to single line, I get the same error before.

Comment: Did you also remove the semicolons?

Comment: No, I don't remove semicolons.

Comment: Needs to be without them, so remove and try again